# How to create a trigger that returns a value to the console in java

Tags: java, postgresql

I would like to use Postgres to create a trigger that returns whenever new information is added to a specific column in a table and return that data to me in the console. How could I do this?

I was thinking in java I could assign a value to this trigger function and that's how it could print get my values printed but is this the best way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger cannot return information you are wanting; they return either an image of the row (generally NEW) or null. Nor can they have out parameters. You may get what you want with [NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html). Something like:

```
create or replace function send_notify()
  returns trigger 
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    NOTIFY "my_channel", <what you want on console>;
    return null; 
end;
$$;

create trigger send_notify_air
  after insert 
     on some_table_name
  for each row 
  execute function send_notify();
```